# How to close all websocket connections

Tags: javascript, websocket

I'm trying to close all websocket connections. Unfortunately I get allways the error:

> TypeError: s.close is not a function

I am using javascript rarely, and I can't find the error...

```
var sockets = [];

function addClient() {

    var socket = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:8080/WebsocketHome/notification");
    socket.onmessage = function (event){
        [...]
    };

    sockets.push(socket);
}


function removeAllClients(){
    for(var s in sockets){
        s.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: it it possible that somewhere you have something *else* being pushed into the array? if you just look at `sockets` in the console window: what does it contain?

Comment: hm `console.log('s: ' + s)` prints s: 0, s: 1, s: 2, ...

Comment: It seems your `sockets.push(socket);` is pushing something else than a socket. Before you push it, `console.log` it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`for` gives you the keys (which are: array indices in this case), not the values; you need:

```
for(s in sockets)
    sockets[s].close();
```

Comment: 2022 update: you may use `for(s of sockets)` for desired effect

Answer (score 3):

incredible, but this code:

```
function removeAllClients(){
    for(var s in sockets){
        s.close();
    }
}
```

iterate over indexes. So I do it now in this way:

```
function removeAllClients(){

    sockets.forEach(function(s) {
        s.close();
    });

}
```

and it works. I'm really surprised...